# Unbound and stopped Service's onDestroy is not called

Tags: android, service

The `Activity` in its onStart() binds to the `MusicPlayService`, and in its onStop() it unbinds the `MusicPlayService`. In its onDestroy() it calls the stopService, but **the  `MusicPlayService`'s onDestroy() is not getting called** at all.

****** UPDATE: it is the isFinishing in the onDestroy() is false.

if press the Back button, the activity::onDestroy() has isFinishing == true, and if press home button the onDestroy() is called (I have the 'dont keep activity alive' setting checked) but the isFinishing == false.

I guess it is the correct behavior, that only activity's finish() will start to set isFinishing == true. Even though the home button will trigger the onDestroy(), the os may still think this is not the true 'finishing'.

Wondering if the new arch-lifecycle LifecycleRegistryOwner could provides some hook for the activity is truly be destroyed.

Here is the snippet of the activity:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    if (!isBound) {
        val bindIntent = Intent(this, MusicPlayService::class.java)
        isBound = bindService(bindIntent, myConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    unbindService(myConnection)
    isBound = false
}


override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    if (isFinishing) {
        val intentStopService = Intent(this, MusicPlayService::class.java)
        stopService(intentStopService)
    }
}
```

Comment: Found it is the checking of isFinishing causing the problem, but why when onDestroy the isFinishing is still false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your eventual question (paraphrased):

> Why would isFinishing ever be false in onDestroy?

Here's the relevant snippet from [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#383):

```
* The final call you receive before your
* activity is destroyed.  This can happen either because the
* activity is finishing (someone called {@link Activity#finish} on
* it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this
* instance of the activity to save space.  You can distinguish
* between these two scenarios with the {@link
* Activity#isFinishing} method.
```

So the `isFinishing` flag is a helper for differentiating between two distinct reasons for `Activity` destruction.

Answer (score 0):

The condition

```
if (isFinishing) {
    val intentStopService = Intent(this, 
MusicPlayService::class.java)
    stopService(intentStopService)
 }
```

which you are checking in the onDestroy() always returns false in onDestroy. isFinishing is usually used in onPause () and returns true there. As onDestroy is called after the activity has already been finished and isFinished returns false. Hence the service destroy code of your implementation is not execured.